# EF Core RemoveRange - IComparable Exception

Tags: c#, entity-framework

im trying to delete some entries from a database in ef core:

```
db.RemoveRange(db.table.Where(x => x.prop == 12));
```

but i get the exception

```
    An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in 
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.dll but was not handled in user code: 'Failed to 
compare two elements in the array.'
 Inner exceptions found, see $exception in variables window for more details.
 Innermost exception     System.ArgumentException : At least one object must implement IComparable.
   at System.Collections.Comparer.Compare(Object a, Object b)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.Internal.ModificationCommandComparer.Compare(ModificationCommand x, ModificationCommand y)
   at System.Collections.Generic.ArraySortHelper`1.InsertionSort(T[] keys, Int32 lo, Int32 hi, Comparison`1 comparer)
   at System.Collections.Generic.ArraySortHelper`1.IntrospectiveSort(T[] keys, Int32 left, Int32 length, Comparison`1 comparer)
   at System.Collections.Generic.ArraySortHelper`1.Sort(T[] keys, Int32 index, Int32 length, IComparer`1 comparer)
```

I already extended the class with:

```
        public int CompareTo(Object x)
    {
        // TODO: Handle x or y being null, or them not having names
        return 1;
    }

    public int CompareTo(Table x)
    {
        return 1;
    }
```

But no luck ...

(remove one item only succeds, trying to delete in a foreach -> exception as above)

the class (simplified):

```
    public partial class Table : IComparable, IComparable<Table>
{
    public int SomeID { get; set; }        
    public int Quantity { get; set; }

    public int CompareTo(Object x)
    {
        return 1;
    }

    public int CompareTo(Cart x)
    {
        return 1;
    }

}
```

Whats the correct way of deleting several items?

**Edit:**
Unable to resolve the Problem i used a stored procedure while finishing the Project. Then i tried RemoveRange again, and, it suddenly worked as expected. Dont know which Change lead to this...

**Update:**
The problem was, that (different from the sample above) the key of the item was a byte-array! Changed it to string, everything works as expected.

Comment: you mean derived from IComparable? yes, i did, see class implementation i added to question

Comment: Perhaps there are some other objects involved? Inspect in debugger which objects are being passed to the `Compare` method.

Comment: The compare method is not called. The Exception states that no method can be found